# My password suddenly will not work to get me into my ubuntu 20.04 system

Tags: boot

Restarting with ESC pressed gives me a menu of F1 System info F2 System Diagnostics F3 Boot menu F10 Bios setup F11 System Recovery.  F1 gives the expected description F2, F9, and  F10 all ask for a unknown password and F11 is ignored and loads the usual password request for booting into the system.
I have tried Pressing each Shift key while restarting. These are simply ignored and the default password request screen loaded. I have been able to access the default grub file but I can not edit it.

Comment: Hi Tim, depending on how proficient you are, you should be able to boot to the usb or cd media, mount the internal hard disk, and edit the `/etc/shadow` file on your computer, which will allow you to reset your password

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're dealing with a BIOS password. Ubuntu will likely not be able to help you reset that, as a BIOS password is stored outside of the system's hard drive and is managed by the firmware, not the OS. If you need to clear a BIOS password, try and look up instructions on how to do so on Google, specifying your machine's manufacturer, model, and model number.

Comment: Also, if this is indeed a BIOS password, this is a hardware-specific question that doesn't involve Ubuntu, and so is probably off-topic here.